# Check if string contains one word or more

Tags: ruby, string, whitespace

When looping through lines of text, what is the neatest way (most 'Ruby') to do an if else statement (or similar) to check if the string is a single word or not?

```
def check_if_single_word(string)
   # code here
end

s1 = "two words"
s2 = "hello"

check_if_single_word(s1) -> false
check_if_single_word(s2) -> true
```

Comment: Trim the string first then search for a space, or match a regular expression. I don't know ruby so can't supply code.

Comment: Why is this worthy of a -1? if we can't use this forum to ask simple questions, then why not?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  One is `string.split.size == 1`.  For example, `"dog cat \t hog".split` => `["dog", "cat", "hog"]` and then `.count` returns the size of the array.  `split disregards the escaped character `\t`.  Be sure you get the answer you want if the string is empty.

Comment: @Bathsheba As someone new to Ruby, I'm always trying to find out what are the most idiomatic ways to achieve a simple task. There are certainly several options - I hope that the different ways of achieving the same simple task might be of interest to other beginners too. That's in a nutshell why I asked the question. That's how I hope to really learn how to approach Ruby in the most natural Ruby way.

Comment: Why do you want to check if it's a single word? Just curious.

Comment: Define a single word.

Comment: @MarkThomas I'm using the Stanford NLP gem to lemmatize words in a wordlist, and add each lemma to the corresponding word entry in a dictionary file, which will allow me to analyse and compare external texts more easily later on. Quite a challenge for a new coder :)

Comment: @sawa a stripped string that doesn't whitespace

Comment: @Bathsheba that's good advice, will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're asking about the 'most Ruby' way, I'd rename the method to `single_word?`

One way is to check for the presence of a space character.

```
def single_word?(string)
  !string.strip.include? " "
end
```

But if you want to allow a particular set of characters that meet *your* definition of word, perhaps including apostrophes and hyphens, use a regex:

```
def single_word?(string)
  string.scan(/[\w'-]+/).length == 1
end
```

Comment: I would give *+1* to  your first code... :) which is `string.include? " "`.

Answer (score 2):

Following your definition of a word given in the comment:

```
[A] stripped string that doesn't [include] whitespace
```

the code would be

```
def check_if_single_word(string)
  string.strip == string and string.include?(" ").!
end

check_if_single_word("two words") # => false
check_if_single_word("New York") # => false
check_if_single_word("hello") # => true
check_if_single_word(" hello") # => false
```

Comment: strip == self - are you using the method 'strip' as a freestanding object? Can this be done with all methods? First time I've seen this.

Comment: Another interesting thing I'm seeing for the first time, negating as a method after the statement. So is //string.include?(" ").! == !string.include?(" ")// ?

Comment: Thanks - v interesting. Is there any reason to go one route or the other, or just personal preference?

Comment: Consistency in chaining successive methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if a space exists in the string.

```
def check_if_single_word(string)
   return !(string.strip =~ / /)
end
```

.strip will remove excess white space that may exist at the start and the end of the string.

`!(myString =~ / /)` means that the string does not match the regular expression of a single space. 
Likewise you could also use `!string.strip[/ /]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here some code may help you out :

```
def check_if_single_word(string)
   ar = string.scan(/\w+/)
   ar.size == 1 ? "only one word" : "more than one word"
end

s1 = "two words"
s2 = "hello"
check_if_single_word s1 # => "more than one word"
check_if_single_word s2 # => "only one word"
```

---

```
def check_if_single_word(string)
   string.scan(/\w+/).size == 1
end

s1 = "two words"
s2 = "hello"
check_if_single_word s1 # => false
check_if_single_word s2 # => true
```

Comment: I like the boolean options either side of the ":" in your 3rd line. Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

a Ruby Way. Extend the calss `String`

```
class String

  def one?
    !self.strip.include? " "
  end

end
```

Then use `"Hello world".one?` to Check if string contains one word or more.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend monkeypatching a builtin to a beginner. Nor would I recommend the name `one?` as it isn't self-explanatory enough.

Comment: Also, you have an error. Try executing this in irb, you'll see it.

Comment: I think this is not monkey patching, because no already existing function is overwritten.